# GeoJSON manipulation library in javascript

Tags: javascript, geojson

I'm manipulating GeoJSON objects in a web application. Leaflet accepts the POJOs with the correct GeoJSON format.

But I'd like to use a specific library that creates those POJOs, taking care of the format specification. A library that provides a solid Object Oriented interface.

I receive my data from a REST API and I need to manually create the GeoJSON objects. I think it is not robust to just use simple JS objects. So, I'd love to have a library that supports that part of the work.

I can't specify more about the data format. The only thing I can say is that I get all that's necessary to create GeoJSON objects. The question aims to find a general purpose library. For example in Python, I'd use something like this: https://github.com/frewsxcv/python-geojson

But I cannot find a similar thing in Javascript. Do you know if such a thing exists?

Comment: Can you clarify the format in which you are receiving the data from the REST API (also what sort of server are you calling)?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that I'm looking for a general purpose library. The format of my data is unimportant at this point.

Comment: Would [this](https://github.com/GaborFarkas/geojson_lite) library solve your problem?

Comment: Turf.js has constructors as well as Spatial operations.

Comment: The reason I ask about the format of the incoming data and its source is that the former may influence the choice of library and the latter might just provide a solution, for instance many geo-data servers will give you GeoJson or if you have JSON that needs a little wrangling to make it geojson, then there is a very simple and robust tool you can use.  Without telling us more about the incoming data and its source all suggestions will be a shot in the dark and possibly overkill for your needs.

Comment: @GaborFarkas that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Sadly, I expected something more tested, robust, production ready. But I like the project and hope it grows

Answer (score 1):

`> I think it is not robust to just use simple JS objects.`

Json (and geojson) is *valid javascript object notation*, so it seems circular to say it is not robust to use simple Js objects. Or said another way, Json == simple Js objects.

I am not trying to be snarky- just saying: just build javascript data structures, then serialize them to geojson strings as necessary.

That said, both the Turf and geojson_lite libraries linked above look pretty great. (bookmarking both of those ones myself)!